# Verdana font issue

Tags: css, fonts, psd

I must implement a website css from psd file. In psd some text is in Verdana, but when I use Verdana in css it appears thicker in a browser than Verdana in the psd file. Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can never trust that fonts are looking the same in the Web and in Photoshop. So you still have to choose the best size/weight for yourself.

The "problem" with Verdana is explained very well on this website:
http://sbpoley.home.xs4all.nl/webmatters/verdana.html

Basically Verdana appears much bigger than other fonts when used in a website, compared to other popular fonts you must use it in 85% of the size you would use Arial or Times.